# How to scale a shape made of points?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, scale

Say I have a shape like this:

[image: larger shape]

And I want to scale it down to this:

[image: smaller shape]

How do I calculate the location of the points (red circles) to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new.x = scale * (old.x - center.x) + center.x
new.y = scale * (old.y - center.y) + center.y
```

Repeat for each point.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!